# How const std::shared_ptr reference upcast works?

Tags: c++, casting, shared-ptr

According to my understanding, when a const shared_ptr& is upcasted, it creates a new shared pointer of the based class pointing to the same (casted) object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Animal
{
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
};

void display(const std::shared_ptr<Animal>& animal)
{
    std::cout << animal.use_count() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto cat = std::make_shared<Cat>();

    std::cout << cat.use_count() << std::endl;
    display(cat);
    std::cout << cat.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

The output of the above code is as follow.

```
sujith@AKLJoincggDLEd:~/sujith$ g++  -std=c++17 main.cpp
sujith@AKLJoincggDLEd:~/sujith$ ./a.out
1
2
1
sujith@AKLJoincggDLEd:~/sujith$
```

My question is what operator does this? Can we get the same behaviour for other reference upcasting as well? Or is it speficially handled for shared_ptr references?

Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: `Can we get the same behaviour for other reference upcasting as well?` Which behavior are you talking about?

Comment: Hi @tkausl, Creating a new object in the upcasting a const reference. I did not mean actual such requirement. But for me creating another new object (shared_ptr<Animal>) in   const shared_ptr<Cat>& casting to const shared_ptr<Animal>& is a magic. Thank you!

Comment: please try to focus one 1 single question only. The conversion is via converting constructor (9) from here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Comment: its not magic. Its implicit conversion: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from `shared_ptr<Cat>` to `shared_ptr<Animal>`. A temporary object is created through conversion and bound to the reference. The same happens in other implicit conversions. For instance, `int x = 3; const float& y = x;` will "invent" a `float` whose value is `3.0f`.

Comment: for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list.

Comment: You get the same "auto-casting" behavior if you had `void display(Animal const* animal);` and a `auto cat = new Cat;`.  The `cat` argument creates an object that is an `Animal const*` which value is set to the `animal` parameter.

Comment: @molbdnilo And because passing by const ref can "invent" objects, it's highly discouraged when the address of the parameter might be taken and compared: pass by pointer to const when you deal with specific objects and might compare their addresses.

Comment: @Eljay Pass by scalar have a lot of rules allowing you to have the right overloaded selected if you have signatures `f(Base*)`  and `f(Der*)` call `f` with a `Der2*` (the overload taking the most derived type is selected); UDT with user defined conversions will have so such preference, it will be ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function that does this is [`std::shared_ptr`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), specifically overload 9:

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r ) noexcept;
```

These are the semantics:

> Constructs a shared_ptr which shares ownership of the object managed
> by r. If r manages no object, *this manages no object either. The
> template overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if Y* is
> not implicitly convertible to (until C++17)compatible with (since
> C++17) T*.

Important is the last sentence. Your `Cat*` (Y*) is convertible to / compatible with your `Animal*` (T*). So, this constructor participates in overload resolution and is selected because it is the only one available (the other overloads do not match).

---

Here is a simplified example that highlights how the general concept works, that `std::shared_ptr` uses in the quoted overload:

```
struct A{};

struct B {
  B(A const& a) {}
};

void foo(B const&) {}

int main() {
  A a;
  foo(a);
}
```

The call to `foo` implicitly creates a `B` object via `B::B(A const&)`. `foo` is then passed a const reference to that temporary `B` object.

The fact that in your example `B` and `A` were types stemming from the same class template is immaterial.